# Different dns entries in docker container than host

Tags: docker, docker-network

When I ping a URL from my Ubuntu system it resolves correctly to the IP of the desired server. When I do the same thing from within my container it resolves to some other IP (I think its an old DNS entry).

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

#### Update

I run the container with the following command:

```sh
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/data-storage dotnet-testbed /bin/bash
```

Pinging Google works:

```
PING google.com (172.217.19.174): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.19.174: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=4.537 ms
```

pinging the myUrl shows the wrong ip and gets stuck:

```
PING myUrl (**.***.***.**): 56 data bytes
```

Comment: Can you display the ping commands?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the following techniques useful to investigate how your Docker container resolves a host…

Search the [hosts database](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html):

```bash
 docker run alpine getent hosts stackoverflow.com       
151.101.1.69      stackoverflow.com  stackoverflow.com
```

Check the [hosts file](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap9sec95.html):

```bash
 docker run alpine cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.3  6a431f90415d
```

Check the hosts added to the container's hosts file explicitly by [`docker run --add-host`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-entries-to-container-hosts-file-add-host):

```bash
 docker run --name=my_cool_container -i -d --add-host stackoverflow.com:127.0.0.1 alpine sh
 docker inspect -f '{{range $index, $value := .HostConfig.ExtraHosts}}{{$value}}
{{end}}' my_cool_container
stackoverflow.com:127.0.0.1
```

But maybe this doesn't have so much to do with Docker. You should run `ifconfig` inside the container and check whether its DNS server is the same as your host machine's. You can also use `dig` to check the DNS answer that it receives.

I'd be very surprised if this was an "old DNS entry" in the *container* (containers are often short-lived). If so: you could fix that by redeploying the container (or learning how to purge its DNS cache).

Most likely: there's some proxy that your host machine uses, but the container does not. By default, Docker containers use bridge networking. If you [switch it to use *host* networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/): the container will use your host's networking stack. This may be enough to make it benefit from your proxy.

Comment: Any image will show the same behaviour (different IP for my domain) and by using --network=host I get the correct Ip.

Comment: It must have been a proxy issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy?... You can set http_proxy as environment variable in your container .. or pass as an argument for building purpouses